# Print to external receipt printer using SenchaTouch with Phonegap

Tags: printing, cordova, sencha-touch

I am creating an application in SenchaTouch. Also i am going to use PHONEGAP to deploy for ios,android and blackberry. In the application i need to print some details like receipt. I dont know how to make print functionality which should be compatible for the above mentioned platforms.

I need to get the list of printer too.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you implement it? I need to do something very similar.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for Android or Blackberry, but iOS apps can print to two types of printers:

1. AirPrint certified printers. You can print to AirPrint printers from an iOS PhoneGap application using the Phonegap print plugin.  https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1113
2. Ones certified by Apple as part of their "MFi Program". I'm only aware of one MFi printer but it's a receipt printer so it could be just what you need (you'd need to write your own PhoneGap plugin though in order to interface with the printer's SDK): http://www.bluebamboo.com/products/show.asp?id=16

Note: when using AirPrint you don't need to worry about the list of available printers. The user is presented with a dialog containing a list of all the available AirPrint printers on their network. Your printjob will be sent to whichever printer they select.

Comment: I found the plugin but does not work on ipad, please you provide a example? ... to convert. ipa the project, "sencha touch" + "index.html (from plugin)" + "PhoneGap build" the print button does nothing

Answer (score 1):

The basic algorithm is to programmatically instantiate an `iframe`, populate it with content, and then invoke its print method as illustrated below:

```
// create print frame
var pFrame = Ext.get('printerFrame');
if (!pFrame) {
  Ext.getBody().insertHtml("beforeEnd","<iframe id='printerFrame' style='display:none'>    </iframe>");
  pFrame = Ext.get('printerFrame');
}

var contentWindow = pFrame.dom.contentWindow;
contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = 'This is some html';
contentWindow.print();
```

Invoking the `print()` method launches the iOS printer chooser, enabling you to print to any AirPrint printer. This technique should also work for Ext JS 4.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know that iOS only supports air printing for select HP printers. Second, I am not even sure blackberry can do that but I may be wrong.

What you need to do is write the phonegap code to interface with the native air print code for iOS, Android's implementation and then BlackBerry.

Answer (score 0):

It may not work for you particular environment, but this solution will work if you can put the effort  in:

Setup a web service on an that accepts print requests with the data to be printed.  Then write a small Windows/Linux/OSX program that polls your web service for new print jobs.  If the program finds a new print request, it sends it to the correct printer.  This could be written as a service or it could be run as a scheduled task.

Now when you need to print from your mobile app, it can make an ajax call to your web service and send the data to be printed.

Comment: reinvent Google Cloud Print?